# Evaluation of e^x with series expansion

Tags: numerical-methods, racket

My code calculates \$e^x\$ with series expansion. Is there any way to make it shorter and cleaner?

```
#lang racket
; evaluate e^x with series expansion, use first 10 terms.

(define (exp x)
  (letrec ([f1 (lambda (n cx cn)
                 ;(writeln (list n cx cn))
                 (if (>= n 10)
                     0
                     (+ (/ cx cn) (f1 (+ n 1) (* cx x) (* cn (+ n 1))))))])
    (+ 1 (f1 1 x 1))
    )
  )

(letrec ([N (read)]
         [rd (lambda (n)
               (unless (zero? n)
                       (define x (read))
                       (writeln (exp x)) (rd (- n 1))))])
  (rd N))
```

Answer (score 1):

### General Programming

1. Using built the built in [exponent function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=expt#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._expt%29%29) from `racket/base` and referencing [Euler's Number](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/base.html?q=euler#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fbase..rkt%29._euler..0%29%29) from `math/base` would probably reduce the likelihood of bugs; increase speed; and allow programming at a higher level of abstraction.
2. An alternative to `read` is the GUI function [`get-text-from-user`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=get-text-from#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._get-text-from-user%29%29) in `racket/gui/base`.

### Example Code

```
#lang racket

(require (only-in math/base
                  euler.0)
         (only-in racket/gui/base
                  get-text-from-user))

(define (get-power-of-e)
  (define x (string->number
             (get-text-from-user "Power of e"
                                 "provide exponent")))
  (expt euler.0 x))
```